# Resolving ORA-02019 error during DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.PUT_FILE()

Tags: oracle, datapump

I am using `DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.PUT_FILE()` on a local Oracle Express instance to transfer a local file to a remote AWS RDS Oracle instance, but I am receiving the following error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER", line 60
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER", line 168
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

I receive this error while executing the following SQL script:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.PUT_FILE(
   'DATA_PUMP_DIR',
   'some_file.txt',
   'DATA_PUMP_DIR',
   'some_file.txt',
   'MY_DATABASE_LINK'
   );
END;
/
```

`MY_DATABASE_LINK` is a public database link located in my local Oracle Express instance:

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK MY_DATABASE_LINK CONNECT TO example_schema IDENTIFIED BY "example_user" USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=example_host_info)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=example_sid)))';
```

I'm fairly confident that the connection string behind the database link is correct, but I'm not sure how to be 100% sure.

The `ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found` error does not make sense because the connection description is defined by the database link. It is not present in `tnsnames.ora`, and I am confident that it doesn't have to be for `DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.PUT_FILE()` to work.

Comment: Is the link working? select * from dual@MY_DATABASE_LINK  ??

Comment: @Pankaj This seems to work - it does not return an error.

Comment: Try and test the connect descriptor - sqlplus username@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=example_host_info)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=example_sid)))"

Comment: @Pankaj After `sudo su; su oracle;` - this prompts me for `oracle` user credentials with `sudo blah`, but does not prompt for `oracle` credentials without `sudo`. So this does work. I don't get any password prompts in the context of running my SQL script.

Comment: If both your link and connect descriptor are working fine from remote host then its a mystery. Don't see any other reason then these.